# Building Fiware Orion context broker on LinuxOne docker (s390x)

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to build Fiware Orion context broker using Dockerfile at:

https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/

As a first step I have tried replacing the FROM image with the "supposed" equivalent of Centos for s390x, ClefOS: https://hub.docker.com/_/clefos :

```
FROM s390x/clefos:7.6.1810
```

It takes a long time and seems to go OK but ends up with the error below. Any ideas? Anybody has successfully built any Orion version docker image on IBM Z? (s390x)

Update: I have added those four libraries in the yum install command in Dockerfile and they are correctly installed but the problem is still there. It seems not just a problem of those boost_* libs missing but some configuration fix needed to "ld" locates them.

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/mongoRegistrationCreate.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/mongoRegistrationDelete.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/connectionOperations.cpp.o
[ 97%] [ 98%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/mongoSubCache.cpp.o
Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/safeMongo.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/compoundResponses.cpp.o
[ 98%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/location.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/compoundValueBson.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/dateExpiration.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libmongoBackend.a
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
[ 99%] Built target mongoBackend
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
Scanning dependencies of target contextBroker
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
[100%] Building CXX object src/app/contextBroker/CMakeFiles/contextBroker.dir/contextBroker.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object src/app/contextBroker/CMakeFiles/contextBroker.dir/orionRestServices.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable contextBroker
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [src/app/contextBroker/contextBroker] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[2]: *** [src/app/contextBroker/CMakeFiles/contextBroker.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2/fiware-orion/BUILD_RELEASE'
make: *** [release] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c adduser --comment "${ORION_USER}" ${ORION_USER} &&     yum -y install epel-release &&     yum -y install       boost-devel       bzip2       cmake       gnutls-devel       libgcrypt-devel       libcurl-devel       openssl-devel       libuuid-devel       make       nc       git       gcc-c++       scons       tar       which       cyrus-sasl-devel &&     curl -kOL http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48.tar.gz &&     tar xvf libmicrohttpd-0.9.48.tar.gz &&     cd libmicrohttpd-0.9.48 &&     ./configure --disable-messages --disable-postprocessor --disable-dauth &&     make &&     make install &&     ldconfig &&     curl -kOL https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/legacy-1.1.2.tar.gz &&     tar xfz legacy-1.1.2.tar.gz &&     cd mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2 &&     scons --use-sasl-client --ssl &&     scons install --prefix=/usr/local --use-sasl-client --ssl &&     curl -kOL https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/archive/v1.0.2.tar.gz &&     tar xfz v1.0.2.tar.gz &&     mv rapidjson-1.0.2/include/rapidjson/ /usr/local/include &&     git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion &&     cd fiware-orion &&     git checkout ${GIT_REV_ORION} &&     make &&     make install &&     strip /usr/bin/contextBroker &&     mkdir -p /var/log/contextBroker &&     mkdir -p /var/run/contextBroker &&     chown ${ORION_USER} /var/log/contextBroker &&     chown ${ORION_USER} /var/run/contextBroker &&     cd /opt &&     if [ ${CLEAN_DEV_TOOLS} -eq 0 ] ; then yum clean all && exit 0 ; fi &&     rm -rf /opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48.tar.gz            /usr/local/include/microhttpd.h            /usr/local/lib/libmicrohttpd.*            /opt/libmicrohttpd-0.9.48            /opt/legacy-1.1.2.tar.gz            /opt/mongo-cxx-driver-legacy-1.1.2            /usr/local/include/mongo            /usr/local/lib/libmongoclient.a            /opt/rapidjson-1.0.2            /opt/v1.0.2.tar.gz            /usr/local/include/rapidjson            /opt/fiware-orion            /usr/share/cracklib            /usr/share/i18n /usr/{lib,lib64}/gconv            &&     yum -y erase git perl* rsync         cmake libarchive         gcc-c++ cloog-ppl cpp gcc glibc-devel glibc-headers         kernel-headers libgomp libstdc++-devel mpfr ppl         scons boost-devel libcurl-devel gnutls-devel libgcrypt-devel         clang llvm llvm-libs         CUnit-devel CUnit         autoconf automake m4 libidn-devel         boost-wave boost-serialization boost-python         boost-iostreams boost boost-date-time         boost-test boost-graph boost-signals         boost-program-options boost-math         openssh openssh-clients libedit hwdata dbus-glib fipscheck* *devel sysvinit-tools         &&     rpm -qa groff | xargs -r rpm -e --nodeps &&     yum clean all && rm -rf /var/lib/yum/yumdb && rm -rf /var/lib/yum/history &&     rpm -vv --rebuilddb &&     find /usr/share/locale -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'en_US' ! -name 'locale.alias' | xargs -r rm -r &&     bash -c 'localedef --list-archive | grep -v -e "en_US" | xargs localedef --delete-from-archive' &&     /bin/cp -f /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl &&     build-locale-archive &&     rm -f /var/log/*log' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

By

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-mt
```

I guess some required dependencies are missing. The solution would be to install them as part of the Dockefile script. However, not sure how to do it in s390x/clefos (in CentOS is a matter of installing the package that contains the dependency using `yum`, the Dockerfile does that).

Comment: Thanks a lot @fgalan . As a Java developer, I am not too used to use c++. Any help on how can I locate which package I need to install with yum to add those libraries? I can easily update the Dockerfile script to add them if I know which are those. Clefos should be the same as Centos on this.

Comment: I have updated Docker file to install those 4 libraries but seems not to be the problem. I'll update the entry above to reflect this...

Comment: Maybe some fix in CMakeList.txt files should be also needed to cover the operating system in which you are compiling.

Comment: I'm using Clefos: https://hub.docker.com/_/clefos Should be "functionally compatible" with CentOS but built for System Z (s390x) :-/